# I am trying to add column to google timeline chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I was analysing the google timeline chart to do some task related to my project.
I took the sample code which is like this

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization',
       'version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
  dataTable.addcolumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Section'});
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'President','section1',          'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    [ 'President','section1',          'John Adams',        new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    [ 'President',         'section1', 'Thomas Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1809, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Vice President', 'section1',    'John Adams',        new Date(1789, 3, 20), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Secretary of State','section1', 'Levi Lincoln',      new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 4, 0)],
    [ 'Secretary of State','section1', 'James Madison',     new Date(1801, 4, 1),  new Date(1809, 2, 2)]]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
</script>

<div id="example3.1" style="width: 1000px; height: 200px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example I have added this one extra column

```
dataTable.addcolumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Section'});
```

in the given example on google timeline chart.

But when I debug this example with this extra column it shows an error

> Uncaught type error undefined is not a function

I don't know how to solve this problem. need speedy solution for this. I am new to google timeline chart and also in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Took me 5 minutes to get it working, but 15 more to understand why it was not working. Its a really small mistake, but you have addcolumn instead of addColumn (c instead of C) . Correct that and it should not give an error on that line. Still will throw a `Invalid data table format: must have 3 or 4 data columns` , as the expected data for a TimeLine is 4 rows

Comment: Thanks silly mistake. But Can you tell me how to pass data in add rows at a time like a array in this

Comment: @RanjeetSIngh what do you mean? Passing data works fine the way you are doing, its just that you can't have 5 rows of data on that chart

Answer (score 1):

Google Timeline does not allow extra columns.  You are only allowed 3 columns if you're omitting the bar label and 4 if it's included.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is a possibility to add more information in the TimeLine Chart

```
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
```

Each Cell in this column,you program such a way, it will have a multi-columnar values.

And Use handler Event to do the JavaScript to get the appropriate information.

If you need more info, let me explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `dummy` column.

Replace:

```
dataTable.addcolumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Section'});
```

With:

```
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'dummy bar label' });
```

Answer (score 0):

like someone here said: you can use role: 'tooltip' to overcome the limit and have an id on your timeline like so:

```
function drawChart() {
    // Define the chart to be drawn.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Date' });
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    data.addColumn({ type: 'number', role: 'tooltip', id: 'Id' }); //THIS IS THE EXTRA LINE - NOTE THE ROLE TYPE

    data.addRows([<?=$js;?>]);

    var options = {      
      colors: ['#0033cc', '#FFD700', '#FF7A00', '#319899', '#3FCA00', '#C20073']
    };

    // Instantiate and draw the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('container'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

    function selectHandler(e) {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        if (selection.length > 0) {
            console.log(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 4)); // THIS IS HOW YOU READ IT
        }
    }

}
```